# How can I change button function in Storyboard mode Xcode

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am new to developing apps for iOS devices, and I just tried out storyboard mode. I wanted to know if there was a way to change the function of the button,
for example, I have three pages, and on the first page I have two buttons, one that leads two the next page and a button that leads to the third page?

I would really appreciate an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant you just control drag from the button to the page you want it to lead to? that is how storyboard works.

IMPORTANT: to go back you DO NOT create a button and make drag it back, instead you create a button and set the code for that button to dismiss the view controller.

Comment: Thanks for the answers but I have a question, is there a limit to the amount of pages in storyboard

Comment: [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; And I dont think there might be a limit, but i doubt someone wants to have tons of screens, thats just against the interface guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the old method in Interface Builder : drag the `IBAction` to your button.

If you plan to use segues, you have to define the segue name in Properties, and implements `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` method.

Comment: Wait is coding needed in storyboard mode?

Comment: You thought storyboard does not require you to write codes? storyboard is just a group of XIBs.